# How to delay/prevent asterisk expansion in bash function parameter?

Tags: bash

I have written a bash function that helps me navigate through a project directory faster. The first parameter to the function is a keyword passed to a python script which determines a base path to cd into. If additional parameters are passed to the function, it will cd into each sub-directory in the order they are passed. For example:

```
$ go intf -> cd to $BASE/interface  
$ go intf foo -> cd to $BASE/interface/foo
```

The problem arises when I use the wildcard - *and* the wildcard is matched in the directory that the function is executed from. So consider the simple directory structure:

```
$BASE/foo1  
$BASE/interface/foo
```

If I'm currently in `$BASE`, and I run:

```
$ go intf foo*
```

My command takes me to `$BASE/interface` and then tries to cd into `foo1` which doesn't exist in the new path. This notation works perfectly fine *unless* the pattern is matched in the original directory.

So here is my function (with error checking omitted). The for-loop at the end is what I am trying to 'fix' for the scenario above. I have tried using `eval "cd [...]"` and other variations of quotation, looping, etc.

```
go() {
  OUTPUT=$(python ~/bin/go.py $1)
  cd "$OUTPUT"
  for i in "${@:2}"; do cd "$i"; done
}
```

So basically, I do *not* want an asterisk to be evaluated until the for-loop `cd` command is issued and I do *not* want to have to wrap each wildcard arg to my function call in quotes. How can I prevent/delay the wildcard expansion to suit my needs?

Comment: You can't. The shell expands wildcards on the command line before it even figures out what command/function is going to be executed, so there's no way for your function to prevent it. To put it another way, your command cannot change standard shell syntax, and the way wildcard expansion happens is part of standard shell syntax.

Comment: What about using `CDPATH=$BASE` instead? With proper tab completion set up, you'll be able to say `cd <tab>` and get completion on the whole directory tree under `$BASE`.

Comment: Well that is disappointing. Thank you for the reply. But good news is I think I may have found a work-around that will allow me to be lazy and not have to type quotes when using the wildcard. It looks like I can 'manually' wrap the arg in asterisks in the function. This appears to work for the case where I've provided the full directory name - just need to find the right syntax for my bash function.

Answer (score 0):

So I had been stuck on this problem but came up with a really simple solution after [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) pointed out that the way I wanted to solve the problem was not possible.

I changed my function from `cd "$i"` to `cd *$i*`:

```
go() {
  OUTPUT=$(python ~/bin/go.py $1)
  cd "$OUTPUT"
  for i in "${@:2}"; do cd *$i*; done
}
```

This solves the corner-case issue I was having, still works for the normal cases, and allows me to be even lazier because I no longer need to add the asterisks :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set the argument to your function.
I will use `ls` as example, but it works the same with `function`.
If you encapsulate the argument with single quote (`'`), bash will not expand the value, but if you don't encapsulate, or do it using double quotes (`"`), than bash will expand it.

See below and example:

```
$ ls /tmp/demo/
dir1  dir2

$ ls /tmp/demo/*
/tmp/demo/dir1:

/tmp/demo/dir2:
$ ls '/tmp/demo/*'
ls: cannot access '/tmp/demo/*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Understood - As I stated in my question, I wanted to avoid having to add quotes when I used an asterisk.